# Image not loading from folder

Tags: angular

I have image in src/assets/images/img.jpg

I'm trying to load image in my Dialog component:

```
<div>
    <img #imageElement src="/src/assets/images/img.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

What I'm getting is this error:

GET http://localhost:3000/src/assets/images/img.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Try `src="/assets/images/img.jpg"`

Comment: Didn't help, still same error.

Comment: Try relative path, and re you sure you have image at specified location.?

Comment: Angular doesn't work like that. You need to copy your assets. Use ng build and have a look to your dist folder, that's all the resources you will have access to when the app is served. Have a look here to learn how to do it https://www.beyondjava.net/angular-assets-configuration Feel free to update your original question if you get stuck :)

Comment: I'm using Angular 4, and this is my angular-cli.json 

{
    "project": {
      "name": "app"
    },
    "apps": [
      {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    ]
}